# Motion of a car rounding a bank

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, centripetal-force, free-body-diagram

When a car is traveling round a banked track as fast as possible, it has a tendency to slip up the slope.

Opposite in the case when the car travels slowly and has a tendency to slip down.

Can someone please give me an intuitive reason as to why this "tendency to slip up or down" occurs.

Answer (score 2):

If you need just an intuitive reason here it is- the primary forces that pushes the car up and down the track is the balance force of centripetal force and tyre friction force. If the friction between the tyre and road is more than the centripetal force (which in turn depends on velocity of vehicle) due to the banking surface (the bank provides the necessary centripetal force for the vehicle to maneuver the curves), the car slips in. And in the other case the car slips away. In case you need qualitative analysis leave a comment..

Comment: Combination of static friction force and the normal reaction's component towards center provide the necessary centripetal force. However, if we increase the velocity beyond a certain limit, the requirement of new (and huge) centripetal force is not satisfied by the combination of static friction + normal reaction's component. And thus the car slips away.